# Handle many API requests in parallel vs async/await

Tags: c#, ajax, multithreading, api, asynchronous

A CPU bound problem is one that requires a CPU for calculations.
An IO bound problem is one that requires to wait for the network, disk or input.
A single API request is IO bound.

The question is, when I make 100 API requests using a for loop, then, do we say that those requests are IO bound? Or do we say that they are CPU bound? Or do we say they are both CPU and IO bound?

Generally for IO bound we use multi threading or if we use single thread we can use async/await. Where as for a CPU bound process we use parallel programming or multi processing or async await with Task.Run.

For my example of 100 API requests in a for loop, is async/await better than multi threading or async/await+Task.Run or TPL?

Comment: So much confusion... Are you _making_ the api calls or is this from the API-perspective? If you are making 100 calls to a network api, then in that client context, it is completely I/O-bound. If you are on the other side, then it depends on what the api is doing. It may be I/O, CPU or mixed.

Comment: And by the way: "single thread asyncwawait" makes no sense whatsoever. In the end, you don't really know, how many threads you'll end up using. Async/Await Tasks abstract from the layer of threading. It _may_ execute on a single thread, or more than one. But in the end: you don't care. It's designed so you don't have to care (with exceptions to that of course).

Comment: _"For my example of 100 api requests in for loop, is async await better than multi threading?"_ - what is your definition of "better"?

Comment: Can you show us how you could use parallel programming (or multithreading) in order to make 100 concurrent I/O-bound API requests? I am asking because the dilemma may not be "parallel vs async/await", but "synchronous vs asynchronous".

Comment: @fildor - suppose I do not use Task.Run, then isn't this guarantee that the same thread will be used?

Comment: _"suppose I do not use Task.Run, then isn't this guarantee that the same thread will be used?"_ - depends. But definitely not "guaranteed".

Comment: Why not? Because at every await, the control of thread will be passed to the caller.

Comment: @fildor - please can you clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 100 I/O-bound operations, then the 100 operations as a whole are still I/O-bound.

CPU-bound is reserved for things that take a non-trivial amount of CPU time. Yes, technically incrementing a counter and starting the next I/O operation does execute CPU opcodes, but the loop would not be considered "CPU-bound" because the amount of time spent doing I/O is vastly higher than the amount of time doing CPU work.

Comment: What factor would influence whether I must use multi threading or async await approach?

Comment: Use asynchrony for I/O-bound work, and parallelism for CPU-bound work.

Comment: 1. Do developers use multi threading like thread.start() or is async await and task the way forward? 2. Parallelism for cpu bound. OK. But I am reading that async await + task helps cpu bound, where as async await helps io bound.

Comment: @variable: You shouldn't use `new Thread` if you can help it; use the TPL or PLINQ for parallel work.

Comment: Stephen- does TPL mean async await Task.Run or does it mean Parallel.ForEach? Sorry for novice question.

Comment: @variable: TPL includes `Parallel`, not `await`. `Task.Run` can also be considered part of TPL.